# jquery progress bar - display quarter ticks and values underneath

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I'm trying to add quarter tick marks, represented by a vertical line, to the jQuery `progressbar`, and then add the corresponding values underneath the tick marks.  I would like these vertical bars to overlay over the actual progress bar.

For example:

-----------------|--------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|

```
        25%              50%           75%          100%
```

All I want to do is to visually represent where the progress is currently located.

Potentially due to my inexperience, I was not able to find an answer to this question.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value in certain places within your code.

//initialize

```
$( ".selector" ).progressbar({ value: 25 });
```

Get or set the value option, after initialization:

// getter

```
var value = $( ".selector" ).progressbar( "option", "value" );
```

// setter

```
$( ".selector" ).progressbar( "option", "value", 25 );
```

Source here http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

EDIT: I assumed this is the progress bar you are attemting to use

Comment: Thanks @Seano666.  This only updates what the current value of progress bar.  I want all 4 values (25%, 50%, 75%, 100%), plus the corresponding tick marks, to be present, regardless of what the actually progress value is.

Comment: Doesn't look like the tick marks are add-able in the stock JQuery UI widget, you might try something like this where you actually create the bar, that was you can add in your own lines etc.  http://workshop.rs/2012/12/animated-progress-bar-in-4-lines-of-jquery/